# Writing to a Record field in Java 14

Tags: java, java-14, java-record

From a brief search on intro’s to Records in Java 14, I see that Record fields are compiled as final instance variables. This seems to imply I can’t write to Record fields.. none of the tutorials mention anything about writing to Record fields either.

Why is that? Why can’t I use a Record in Java 14 like I would use a struct in C?

Thanks for any insight

Comment: The JDK team have discussed adding "withers" (mutators) to records in the future. For now, I've written a record builder library that adds a Builder and Withers to records. Libraries like this will have to suffice until new features are added by Oracle: https://github.com/Randgalt/record-builder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Records provide a compact syntax for declaring classes which are
> transparent holders for **shallowly immutable data**
>
> ...
>
> The components of a record are implicitly final. This restriction embodies an
> *immutable by default* policy that is **widely applicable for data aggregates**.

[Source](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359)

Being immutable, at least shallowly, is precisely the point. Records are designed as value types, so no, you cannot change them.

Comment: Another perhaps more useful document is [Data Classes and Sealed Types for Java](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/datum.html) which goes into the design decisions involved, particularly the part about Algebraic Annie, Boilerplate Billy, JavaBean Jerry,  POJO Patty, Tuple Tommy, and Values Victor.

Comment: @DavidConrad That’s a nice link, thanks. The part: “For records, we make a similar trade; we give up the flexibility to decouple the classes API from its state description, in return for getting a highly streamlined declaration (and more).”  I think if we were to model compact state, it make more sense that the State can be modified. I’m not sure if programmers in Java can really make use of an immutable State more than a mutable compact State.

Comment: @ppp Programmers in Java are able to make use of an immutable state of a String just fine. You can add methods like "withX" to your record to return a new record with a different value for a field.

Comment: @DavidConrad thanks, yeah, that’s what I had ended up doing. On another note, technically if you want mutable primitives, can wrap in an Object, despite some much code smell

Comment: @ppp Your use of the word "compact" belies your assumption that the main purpose of records is syntactic concision, but that is not the case.  The main purpose is semantic clarity; that you get syntactic concision as well is a bonus.  Records are _nominal tuples_ (Tommy wins.)  Tuples are generally immutable (I'm sure there are counterexamples, but I can't think of any right now.)

Comment: @BrianGoetz yes, you hit the nail perfectly. I indeed was valuing Records primarily as a compact type (ie, a “struct”). I wasn’t thinking of its use as a Value type as the answered above said, which then makes sense that it must be immutable. I see the latter’ s benefit now (for modeling valid type-semantics I suppose — not too good on this so could be wrong).  Thanks for your kind insight.